# Não consigo fazer o submit do formulário!

Tags: php, html, jquery, modal

Tenho este formulário em uma Modal, mas quando dou submit ele não envia nada pelo método post ou get, e o problema que eu encontrei foi o próprio modal, ele não faz submit dentro do modal.
Alguém poderia me dar um ajuda, errei em algo na criação do modal ou do form, segue o codigo que criei. Obrigado desde já.

```
<div class='modal-header'>
    <h5 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLabel' style='text-align: center !important;margin-left:40%;font-size:1.8em;font-weight:bold'>Registro</h5>
    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'> 
        <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class='modal-body'>
    <form method='post' action='GG.php'>
        <div class='form-group row'>
            <label style='font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important' class='col-5'>Ordem de serviço</label>
            <input class='col-6' type='number' name='ordem' id='ordem0'>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group row'>
            <label style='font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important' class='col-5'>Prisma</label>
            <input class='col-6' type='number' maxlength='2' id='Prisma0' name='prisma'>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group row'>
            <label style='font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important' class='col-5'>Previsão de saída </label>
            <input class='col-6' type='time' name="Hsaida" id='HSaida0'>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group row'>
            <label style='font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important' class='col-5'>Funcionário</label>
            <input class='col-6' type='text' name='func' id='func0'>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group row'>
            <label style='font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important' class='col-5'>Carro</label>
            <input class='col-6' type='text' name='carro' id='carro0'>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group row'>
            <label style='font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important' class='col-5'>Placa</label>
            <input class='col-6' type='text' name='placa' id='placa0'>
        </div>

        <input style='margin-left:82%' type='submit' class='btn' value='Enviar' onclick='animacao(0)' data-dismiss='modal' style='margin-top: 20px;'>

    </form>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["ordem"]) || isset($_POST["func"]) ||isset( $_POST["prisma"]) || isset($_POST["Hsaida"]) || isset($_POST["carro"]) || isset($_POST["placa"])){
    $ordem = $_POST["ordem"];
        $func = $_POST["func"];
        $prisma = $_POST["prisma"];
        $saida = $_POST["Hsaida"];
        $carro = $_POST["carro"];
        $placa = $_POST["placa"];
        echo $ordem;
        echo $func;
        echo $prisma;
        echo $saida;
        echo $carro;
        echo $placa;
    }
?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

Ainda estou aprendendo usar o Javascript então ignorem as gambiarras xD.

```
function animacao(ide){

    var valorr = document.getElementById("HSaida"+ide);
    console.log(valorr.value);
    var horaF = valorr.value;
    var agora = new Date();
    var horas = Horas(agora.getHours());
    var minutos = Horas(agora.getMinutes());
    var total = horas + ":" + minutos;
    console.log(diferencaHoras(total,horaF));
    var Tempo = diferencaHoras(total,horaF);
    var id = "#mudaCor"+ide;
    var parteTempo = Tempo / 4;
    // console.log("o ide é: "+id);
    // console.log("O quarto de hora é"+parteTempo);
    var cont = 0;
    var inter = setInterval(function(){
        // console.log("caiu cont = "+ cont);
        if (cont == 0) {
            $("#mudaCor"+ide).css("background-color","green");
        }
        if(cont == parteTempo){
            $("#mudaCor"+ide).css("background-color","yellow");
        }
         if(cont == parteTempo+parteTempo){
            $("#mudaCor"+ide).css("background-color","orange");
        }
         if(cont == parteTempo+parteTempo+parteTempo){
            $("#mudaCor"+ide).css("background-color","red");
        }
        if(cont == parteTempo+parteTempo+parteTempo+parteTempo+1){
            $("#mudaCor"+ide).css("background-color","black");
            $("#CorPrisma"+ide).css("color","white");
            $("#CorCarro"+ide).css("color","white");
            $("#CorFuncio"+ide).css("color","white");
            $("#CorPlaca"+ide).css("color","white");
            clearInterval(inter);
        }
        cont++;
    },1000);
    var carroo = document.getElementById("carro"+ide);
    var carro = carroo.value;
    var serviçoo = document.getElementById("ordem"+ide);
    var serviço = serviçoo.value;
    var funci = document.getElementById("func"+ide);
    var func = funci.value;
    var valorr = document.getElementById("HSaida"+ide);

    var prisma = document.getElementById("Prisma"+ide);
    var prisma_valor = prisma.value;
    var placaa = document.getElementById("placa"+ide);
    var placa = placaa.value;
    document.getElementById("mudaCor"+ide).innerHTML ="<div style='text-align:center;'><p id='CorPrisma"+ide+"' style='margin-bottom:0 !important;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold;line-height: 1'>"+ prisma_valor +"</p><input type='number' id='Prisma"+ide+"' style='display:none' value='"+prisma_valor+"'><p id='CorCarro"+ide+"' style='margin-bottom:0 !important;font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:0px;line-height: 1'>"+carro+"</p><p id='CorPlaca"+ide+"' style='font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom: 0 !important;'>"+placa+"</p><p id='CorFuncio"+ide+"' style='font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom: 0 !important;'>"+func+"</p></div><button style='margin-left:44px;height:23px !important;width:100px;font-size:90%;padding:0;position:absolute;bottom:1%' type='button' class='btn btn-dark' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal"+ide+"' style='margin-left: 40px'> Visualizar </button> <div class='modal fade' id='exampleModal"+ide+"' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'> <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'> <div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'> <h5 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLabel' style='text-align: center !important;margin-left:40%;font-size:1.8em;font-weight:bold'>Registro</h5><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div><div class='modal-body'><br><input type='number' id='IdMudaCor"+ide+"' style='display:none' value='"+ide+"'><div class='row'><p style='text-align:right;font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important' class='col-5'> Ordem de serviço: </p><p class='col-3' style='font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important'>"+ serviço +"</p></div><input type='text' id='Oserviço"+ide+"' style='display:none' value='"+serviço+"'><div class='row'><p class='col-5' style='text-align:right;font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important'> Funcionário: </p><p class='col-3' style='font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important'>"+ func +"</p></div><input type='text' id='Funcio"+ide+"' style='display:none' value='"+func+"'><div class='row'><p class='col-5' style='text-align:right;font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important'> Horário de entrada:</p><p class='col-3' style='font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important'> "+total +"</p></div><input type='time' id='HoraIni"+ide+"' style='display:none' value='"+total+"' ><div class='row'><p class='col-5' style='text-align:right;font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important'> Previsão de saída:</p><p class='col-3' style='font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important'> "+ horaF+"</p></div><input type='text' id='HorarioSaida"+ide+"' style='display:none' value='"+horaF+"'><div class='row'><p class='col-5' style='text-align:right;font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important'> Carro:</p><p class='col-3' style='font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important'>" +carro +"</p></div><input type='text' id='NomeCarro"+ide+"' style='display:none' value='"+carro+"'><div class='row'><p class='col-5' style='text-align:right;font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important'> Placa:</p><p class='col-3' style='font-size:1.2em;padding-left:8px !important'>"+placa+"</p><input type='text' id='Placa"+ide+"' style='display:none' value='"+placa+"' ></div><button class='btn btn-primary' style=';margin-right:10px' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#CollapseExample"+ide+"' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='CollapseExample"+ide+"' onclick='enviar("+ide+")' >Alterar</button><button class='btn btn-primary' style='margin-right:10px' onclick='enviar("+ide+")' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#multiCollapseExample"+ide+"' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='multiCollapseExample"+ide+"'>Extender</button><button class='btn btn-danger' style='margin-left:40%' data-dismiss='modal' onclick='deletar("+ide+")'>Terminar</button><div style='margin-top: 10px;' class='collapse multi-collapse' id='multiCollapseExample"+ide+"'><div class='card card-body'><div style='margin-bottom : -0px !important;' class='form-group row'><label style='font-size: 1.2em;' class='col-7'>Nova previsão de término</label><input id='HoraExtendida"+ide+"' class='col-3' type='time'><button  class='btn' onclick='extender("+ide+")' data-dismiss='modal'>Alterar</button></div></div></div> <div class='collapse' id='CollapseExample"+ide+"' style='margin-top:10px'><div class='card card-body'><div class='form-group row'><label class='col-5' style='font-size: 1.2em;padding-left: 8px !important;'>Ordem de serviço</label><input class='col-6' type='number' value='"+serviço+"' name='ordem' id='ordem"+ide+"'></div><div class='form-group row'><label style='font-size: 1.2em;padding-left: 8px !important;' class='col-5'>Prisma</label><input class='col-6' type='number' id='AltPrisma"+ide+"' value='"+prisma_valor+"' name='prisma'></div><div class='form-group row'><label style='font-size: 1.2em;padding-left: 8px !important;' class='col-5'>Funcionario</label><input class='col-6' type='text' value='"+func+"' name='func' id='func"+ide+"'></div><div class='form-group row'><label style='font-size: 1.2em;padding-left: 8px !important;' class='col-5'>Carro</label><input class='col-6' type='text' name='carro' value='"+carro+"' id='carro"+ide+"'></div><div class='row'><label style='font-size: 1.2em;padding-left: 8px !important;' class='col-5'>Placa</label><input class='col-6' type='text' name='placa' value='"+placa+"' id='AtPlaca"+ide+"'></div><div class='row'><button class='btn' type='button' style='left:77%;position:relative' onclick='alterar("+ide+")' data-dismiss='modal'>Salvar</button></div></div></div></div></div> </div></div></div>";

}
```

Comment: Não indica nenhum erro, coloque o código de back-end e o javascript que está utilizar para animacao(0)

Comment: o javascript de animacao é muito extenso e não a necessidade dele, testei sem ele e não houve erro.

Comment: @Douglas não acusa nenhum erro? Porque fiz um teste aq e funcionou normal

Comment: Não acusa nenhum erro, irei enviar o código de animação , vai que por algum motivo o problema seja ele,

Comment: O seu código funciona, não responda à sua pergunta, edite a sua pergunta.

Comment: Deve haver um erro então no Onclick , porque aqui não esta funcionando @JorgeCosta

Comment: Tira o onclick e testa

Answer (score 0):

Não deu pra mim executar aqui seu código por falta de tempo, mas o que faltou foi você pegar o ID do formulario.

```
 <form method='post' action='GG.php' id="formid">
```

No javascript você pega esse id e atribui a uma variável como fez com os Input

```
var formid = document.getElementById("formid");
```

Ao final do seu código JavaScript você chama a função para submeter o formulário.

```
formid.submit();
```

Isso será responsável por submeter seu formulário ao arquivo GG.php pelo metodo POST que você definiu.

Por que isso aconteceu?

No botão de submit você esta chamando a função animacao() através do onclick. Porém essa função esta apenas recebendo os valores e estava faltando submeter esse dados. Para submeter o formulário isso é feito através do formid.submit().

Comment: Acho que só pelo fato de ser um input type="submit" ele já "submita" direto, não? A menos que na função animacao() houvesse um e.preventDefault.

Comment: Tenta retirar o type submit e deixar somente pela função onclick. Eu já passei por esse problema, eu creio que o submit não está funcionando por que o script eh executado impedindo do formulário ser enviado.